# Генератор удобнопроизносимых (Pronounceable) паролей

Tags: алгоритм

Ищу какую-либо информацию по уже существующим алгоритмам реализации такого генератор (например FIPS-181), только посвежее. Гугл выдаёт в основном ссылки на онлайн генераторы :-).

Может кто обладает информацией, в какую сторону копать?

Comment: [Генератор паролей](https://1informer.com/generator-passwords-online/) ( ссылка с бомбой)

Answer (score 0):

Почитайте [pwgen](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pwgen/). Он как раз генерирует pronounceable passwords. Кому как, конечно :)

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто взять несколько случайных слов (только словарь должен быть большой). Слова обычно хорошо читаются.

https://xkcd.com/936/

[image: xkcd]